# SQL timeout on Azure website suddenly started when return large number (1500) rows

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, sqlexception

Azure Website with EF6 just started to get timeout on pages where I retrieve more than about 1000 rows. (unsure about the limit, works on 400 or less, fails on 1500 or more)

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.  This failure occurred while attempting to connect to the routing destination. The duration spent while attempting to connect to the original server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=1; handshake=21; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=1;  ]
```

The app has been running smoothly for several month I just noticed today. Any ideas?

(In case the error is still present: Page with err: http://fartslek.no/fartslek/15 Page without err: http://fartslek.no/fartslek/3 )

Comment: How long is your timeout period? Are you hitting 100% DTUs when your query is timing out?

Comment: @JosephIdziorek Thanks for looking into this. Never set a timeout - it usually respond within less than 1 sec so I did'nt tweak the timeoutsettings. I noticed the DTU peaked into 100% when the error was present. The error seems to have gone, and the DTU is down at max 20% when I hit it hard. Strange.